# Which design pattern to use for splitting of complex function?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am having trouble determining which design pattern I should use for this situation. I currently have a function which takes in a ENUM and uses variables from the class itself to do calculations. There are multiple equations / ways to get the calculated variable using different parameters. Currently, I have something which uses the parents class variables and takes in a enum determining which case it is. I want to split up the function and make it where a user has to pass variables to the function / split up the function and not rely on the parent class variables. For example:

```
    public double CalculateVariable(double argument, VariableType varType)
    {
        var returnedVariable = 0.0;
        switch (varType)
        {
            case 1:
                //Use Equation 1 using variables (a,b,c,d) from parent class + argument
                break;
            case 2:
                //Use Equation 2 using variables (a,c,f,g) from parent class + argument
                break;
            case 3:
                //Use Equation 3 using variables (a,b,c,f) from parent class + argument
                break;
        }

        return returnedVariable;
    }
```

Is it proper to have some sort of Builder pattern to accomplish my goal of splitting up this function or is it better to have 5 different functions which says: `CalculateVariableUsingXMethod`, `CalculateVariableUsingYMethod`, `CalculateVariableUsingZMethod`. Which design pattern would I use?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you not defer to "authority" but depend on your own best judgement.

The way I would decide is to ask two questions:

1) What is easiest to follow, in the future when I've forgotten what I did here?

2) How is this likely to be changed in the future, after I or another person learns more? How can I make those changes easy?

Comment: 1) The equations are simple one liners which use different variables for each one. Some variables overlap between the equations.

2) This will not change in the future. There are only 5 ways to calculate this variable using 5 different equations. The main problem is separating the use of the variable from the parent class so it is easier to test. It would be easy to make 5 different functions, however, I feel like there's a clean way to bundle it together with some sort of pattern. 

3) I may be overthinking all this and the best solution is to just create a function for each case.

Comment: @Mohamad: It sounds to me like it doesn't make much difference, but you are the final judge. (It's good to get outside opinions, but sometimes the advice you get is more dogmatic than rational.) Good luck.